# Expose ReactClass using WebPack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to expose a ReactClass, using WebPack, to reuse it at different html pages. Is it possible? What is the correct way? For simplicity, I'll do an example using two times at one html (But it should be used in a lot of different html in the real application)

All the source are available here:
https://github.com/mqueirozcorreia/React-Fundamentals/tree/video2

The `webpack.config.js` successfully creates the bundled file and the code is below:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

The ReactClass is at `app\MyReactClass.js` which the code is the following:

```
var React = require('react');

var MyReactClass = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>MyReactClass = Hello {this.props.name}</div>
    )
  }
});
```

And the MyReactClass is exposed the `app\index.js` as follows:

```
...
require("expose?MyReactClass!./MyReactClass.js");
```

The global variable "MyReactClass" has an instance of an Object (As the alert shows), but when I try to use it at `dist\index.html` to `ReactDOM.render()`, it throws that error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components).
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js Line
>   18794

`dist\index.html` partial code:

```
...

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <div id="component1"></div>
  <div id="component2"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(MyReactClass);
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyReactClass, { name: 'Component1' }), document.getElementById('component1'));
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyReactClass, { name: 'Component2' }), document.getElementById('component2'));
</script>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure out what I was missing.

Just need to module.exports the `MyReactClass` variable to work:

```
module.exports = MyReactClass;
```

So the MyReactClass.js looks like this now

```
var React = require('react');

var MyReactClass = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>MyReactClass = Hello {this.props.name}</div>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = MyReactClass;
```

https://github.com/mqueirozcorreia/React-Fundamentals/blob/ba19aa5cff21f0c4881901e0a96aed6ddaea8e18/app/MyReactClass.js